# how to choose the board design in a multiplayer game?

Tags: game-design, multiplayer

I'm making a Nine Men's Morris board game in which players can play with other online players.

But my problem is in steps before starting the game between two players.

This is what I thought about:

> 1- Player B requests to play with Player A
>
> 2- If player A accept the request, the game will start.

I need a step in between, so that they can choose a board design, but I don't know who should choose it or how.

Is there any better way in maching two players or how to select a borad map? Any ideas is much appreciated.

Comment: There's no best answer to this. I recommend discussing it with us in [chat]

Comment: Have you examined models commonly used for map & mode selection in matchmaking systems in commercial games? Up-front selection, private match host configuration, voting, playlists, and fixed map rotation come to mind, all of which might be applicable to your situation. But none is universally "better" — you'd need to evaluate each option in the context of your game's goals and expected player base.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks.. In the game, I like they both have a chance to select which board to play together. Since they are two players, voting won't work. I searched but couldn't find a model for this situation, maybe I'm bad in searching. The only option I can think of is to let the first player select the board, and other player choose opponent based on his selection.

Comment: 1) Your criteria belong in the question, not in the comments. 2) Voting can totally work for 2 players, you just need a means to break ties, and again here there are lots of options (eg. host wins, flip a coin, score voting where the points you spend are a limited resource or handicap...) It's not the case that there is no model for this situation, rather, the problem is that there are many models and you haven't defined your criteria clearly enough to select one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have the request include a proposal for the board design. The receiver can either

- reject the challenge completely
- accept the challenge with the proposed board, or
- make a counter-proposal with a different board

When a player is just looking for an opponent and does care more about the board they play on than about who their opponent is, you could also do matchmaking in the other way: When a player wants to play, they announce that they are available for play. When they do that, they decide which board they would like to play on. Other players can view the list of available players with their chosen boards and pick one to challenge.